# How to update Vuex before the webpage window closes in Vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i want to connect non-parent-child components with vuex.

When A component open Target component, update Vuex.
When B component opens Target component, if it is saved in Vuex, I want to focus it, and if it is not saved, I want to open it anew.

1. called beforeDestory in LifeCycle hooks
2. called before in LifeCycle hooks
3. called beforeRouteLeave in LifeCycle hooks

but nothing is running.

how can i do?

Comment: You can try `beforeEach` router hook.

Comment: `beforeEach` used to next page. but I want to close window.
so `beforeEach` is not proper solution.

Comment: Then try with `window.onbeforeunload`